# Receiving "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error on login page

Tags: login, errors, security, user-registration

I am using a new domain for my WordPress directory in different server. When I click the meta links such "Login" or "register", I get this page:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame
>
> To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
>
> What you can try:
> Open this content in a new window

How can I fix this?

Comment: This just happens from the new domain ....

Comment: Try entering the website URL in a new tab/window. It that doesn't work, enter `http://yourdomain.com/wp-login.php` in a new browser tab/window

Answer (score 7):

Since version 3.4 (or earlier?) WordPress sends a special HTTP header (not in HTML) on login and admin pages:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

[image]

So your browser will show you some text built into the browser, not sent from WordPress.

From `wp-includes/default-filters.php`:

```
add_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header', 10, 0 );
```

You *could*  create a plugin and disable these headers:

```
remove_action( 'login_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
remove_action( 'admin_init', 'send_frame_options_header' );
```

But then your login can be used for [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#Server_and_client). Someone might register a domain with a very similar name, embed your login as background iframe and log the login credentials when you try to type them in.

That’s not fictional. It actually happened, that’s why WordPress implemented this.

Drop the `iframe`. Try to find a better solution.